# Why isn't name: attribute making it the #destroy action inside the params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

I have a `app/views/shared/stage_items/_destroy.html.erb` partial that looks like the following:

```
<%= link_to 'Remove', stage_item_path(stage_item), name: "request_origin[#{controller.controller_name}]", method: :delete %>
```

I was expecting the find `"request_origin"` in the params when it hits the `StageItems#destroy` action. I set a `binding.pry` there and `p`ed out the `params` but it's not there:

```
[2] pry(#<StageItemsController>)> pp params
{"_method"=>"delete",
 "authenticity_token"=>
  "1UaOESQFsvDwkZ5QQReS91UVmacmM8FpsV5O+mSoEwPRiS2JvfTNPCLDJlPSjo1XLwSGR5gWtj9IqoNIAp/Z9A==",
 "controller"=>"stage_items",
 "action"=>"destroy",
 "id"=>"8"}
```

I looked at the rendered html and the `name` attribute is there:

```
<a name="request_origin[stage_batches]" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/stage_items/8">Remove</a>
```

Why isn't `"request_origin"` making it into the `#destroy` action inside the `params`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get get extra params by passing them in the path:

```
<%= link_to 'Remove', stage_item_path(:id => stage_item.id, :name => "request_origin[#{controller.controller_name}]"), method: :delete %>
```